# front post submit using wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor

I am making my theme with studying. 
I want front-end posting that can be written by users.

I made form. like this.

```
<form class="rnm_fe_write_contets">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="rnm_fe_wr_textbox">
                        <input name="fe_title" class="rnm_fe_wr_textarea" placeholder="Title" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="fe_wr_textbox">
                        <?php
                        $distribution = '';
                        wp_editor(
                            $distribution, 
                            'feeling', 
                            array(
                                'wpautop' => true,
                                'media_buttons' => false,
                                'textarea_rows' =>10,
                                'tabindex' => 4,
                                'tinymce' => array(
                                    'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, temp',
                                ),
                            )
                        );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
            <input name="fe_submit" type="submit" />

        </form>
```

And I will submit in front-end like this.

```
<?php
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => isset($_POST['fe_title']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['fe_title']) : '',
        'post_content' => '', // how to get this contents from wp_editor??

        'post_status' => 'pending',
        'post_type' => 'feeling',                

    );  



    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    if( is_wp_error( $post_id ) || !$post_id ){
        wp_redirect( site_url('/feeling-submit/') . '?result=failure' );
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

But I don't know how to get the input-data from wp_editor. 
Can I have some help?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `$_POST['feeling']`? - `feeling` is editor id.

Comment: I found answer with googling. :: $content = $_POST['wp_editor id'];

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a new post without logging into the WordPress dashboard or allow your visitors a way to submit content of their own, you can do this by front end post submission.

In this post I will show you the way to submit a post from the front end. Let’s start…

You need to follow the below essential steps for making a form for user submitted posts

Step 1. Create a form by which a user can submit the post title, content, tags, category, featured image. You can put this code into your theme functions.php or any other file.

```
add_shortcode( 'themedomain_frontend_post', 'themedomain_frontend_post' );
    function themedomain_frontend_post() {
        themedomain_post_if_submitted(); ?>
        <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p><label for="title"><?php echo esc_html__('Title','theme-domain'); ?></label><br />
                <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
            </p>

            <?php wp_editor( '', 'content' ); ?>

            <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?></p>

            <p><label for="post_tags"><?php echo esc_html__('Tags','theme-domain'); ?></label>

            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>

            <input type="file" name="post_image" id="post_image" aria-required="true">

            <p><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>
        
        </form>
    <?php
    }
```

Step 2. Capturing the input from the front-end user post submission form. You can also put this code into your theme functions.php or any other file.

```
function themedomain_post_if_submitted() {
    // Stop running function if form wasn't submitted
    if ( !isset($_POST['title']) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
        'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
        'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']), 
        'tags_input'    => $_POST['post_tags'],
        'post_status'   => 'draft',   // Could be: publish
        'post_type'     => 'post' // Could be: 'page' or your CPT
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
    
    // For Featured Image
    if( !function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    if($_FILES) {
        foreach( $_FILES as $file => $array ) {
            if($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
            }
            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
        }
    }
    if($attach_id > 0) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id,'_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
    }

    echo 'Saved your post successfully! :)';
}
```

Step 3. Paste the form shortcode where you want to display the form

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[themedomain_frontend_post]'); ?>
```

Comment: This is copy-pasted from https://techsolutionshere.com/wordpress-front-end-post-submission-without-plugin/ Did you write that yourself originally, are you Asia Khanom? Else I don't think that's really allowed.